# Axios, graphql: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: axios, graphql

Maybe it's duplicated anyway i've searched this specific case without finding anything related.

I'm working to plot a chart with tradingview and bitquery api using axios and graphql

The config of my query goes like this:

```
            Bitquery.endpoint, {
                query: Bitquery.GET_COIN_INFO,
                variables: {
                    "tokenAddress": symbolName
                },
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "X-API-KEY": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://localhost:3000",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" :" GET, POST, OPTIONS",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Origin, Content-Type, Accept"                    
                }
            }
        );
```

But i still receiving this error on console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://graphql.bitquery.io/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Could someone give me a hint upon this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This query did worked:

```
const response = await fetch(
            Bitquery.endpoint, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "X-API-KEY": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                },
                variables: {
                    "tokenAddress": symbolName
                },
                mode: 'cors',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    query:`
{
  ethereum(network: bsc) {
    dexTrades(
      options: {desc: ["block.height", "transaction.index"], limit: 1}
      exchangeAddress: {is: "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73"}
      baseCurrency: {is: "0xe87e15b9c7d989474cb6d8c56b3db4efad5b21e8"}
      quoteCurrency: {is: "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"}
    ) 
    {
      block {
        height
        timestamp {
          time(format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
        }
      }
      transaction {
        index
      }
      baseCurrency {
        name
        symbol
        decimals
      }
      quotePrice
    }
  }
}
`
                })
            }
        )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {return result})
        // const coin = response.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades[0].baseCurrency; 
        // console.log(response.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades[0].quotePrice); 
        console.log(response);
```